# Android - TabLayout similar to android market / superuser app

Tags: android, layout, tabs

There is anybody who knows what component is used to create the tab layout that superuser uses?

horizontal gesture changes view and above view names (with green fading).

Regards,
Carlos

Answer (score 0):

Looks like GridView's inside ViewFlipper . Button used for tab Navigation can be kept inside HorizontalScroller

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [`ViewPager`](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).